# Single update duplicated rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, update

**Source:**

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
| Productid | Imagetype |     Imagename     | Website | Thumb90 | Thumb200 | Thumb500 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|   3144000 | small     | 3144000_small.jpg | Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144005 | medium    | 3144005_medium.jpg| Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144005 | medium    | 3144005_medium.jpg| Google  |       0 |        1 |        0 |
|   3144005 | medium    | 3144005_medium.jpg| Google  |       0 |        0 |        1 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

**Traget:**

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
| Productid | Imagetype |     Imagename     | Website | Thumb90 | Thumb200 | Thumb500 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|   3144000 | small     | 3144000_small.jpg | Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144005 | medium    | 3144005_medium.jpg| Google  |       1 |        1 |        1 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

How can this be done in single update ?

My Sample :

```
UPDATE TARGET
SET ImageName  = SOURCE.ImageName,
    Website    = SOURCE.Website,
    Thumb90    = ISNULL(SOURCE.Thumb90,TARGET.Thumb90),
    Thumb200   = ISNULL(SOURCE.Thumb200,TARGET.Thumb200),
    Thumb500   = ISNULL(SOURCE.Thumb500,TARGET.Thumb500)        
FROM [luannw2016].[ImageThumbnailTrack] AS TARGET
INNER JOIN #ImageThumbnailTrack AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.ProductId = SOURCE.ProductId
AND TARGET.ImageType = SOURCE.ImageType
```

Comment: Does your target table already have the rows that you want to update from source? Or do you need to also handle inserts? And what about potential deletes? Merge could handle that, but there are performance concerns around it. Why just the single update?

Comment: If it is not possible in single update then please show me the best way to achieve this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Merge is not the best performing solution, based on your requirements this would handle what you requested (as it would insert rows that did not exist on the target). I put a quick schema together that may not match yours, but gives you the idea.

```
DECLARE @DestTable TABLE
(
  Productid BIGINT ,
  ImageType VARCHAR(10) ,
  ImageName VARCHAR(100) ,
  Website VARCHAR(20) ,
  Thumb90 TINYINT ,
  Thumb200 TINYINT ,
  Thumb500 TINYINT
);
DECLARE @SourceTable TABLE
    (
      Productid BIGINT ,
      ImageType VARCHAR(10) ,
      ImageName VARCHAR(100) ,
      Website VARCHAR(20) ,
      Thumb90 TINYINT ,
      Thumb200 TINYINT ,
      Thumb500 TINYINT
    );

INSERT  INTO @SourceTable
        ( Productid, ImageType, ImageName, Website, Thumb90, Thumb200,
          Thumb500 )
VALUES  ( 3144000, 'small', '3144000_small.jpg', 'Google', 1, 0, 0 )
,       ( 3144005, 'medium', '3144005_medium.jpg', 'Google', 1, 0, 0 )
,       ( 3144005, 'medium', '3144005_medium.jpg', 'Google', 0, 1, 0 )
,       ( 3144005, 'medium', '3144005_medium.jpg', 'Google', 0, 0, 1 );

;
WITH    cteConvergedProducts
          AS ( SELECT   Productid ,
                        ImageType ,
                        ImageName ,
                        Website ,
                        MAX(Thumb90) AS Thumb90 ,
                        MAX(Thumb200) AS Thumb200 ,
                        MAX(Thumb500) AS Thumb500
               FROM     @SourceTable
               GROUP BY Productid ,
                        ImageType ,
                        ImageName ,
                        Website
             )
    MERGE INTO @DestTable AS TARGET
    USING cteConvergedProducts AS SOURCE
    ON SOURCE.Productid = TARGET.Productid
        AND SOURCE.ImageType = TARGET.ImageType
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ( Productid ,
                 ImageType ,
                 ImageName ,
                 Website ,
                 Thumb90 ,
                 Thumb200 ,
                 Thumb500
               )
        VALUES ( SOURCE.Productid ,
                 SOURCE.ImageType ,
                 SOURCE.ImageName ,
                 SOURCE.Website ,
                 SOURCE.Thumb90 ,
                 SOURCE.Thumb200 ,
                 SOURCE.Thumb500
               )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
               ImageName = SOURCE.ImageName ,
               Website = SOURCE.Website ,
               Thumb90 = SOURCE.Thumb90 ,
               Thumb200 = SOURCE.Thumb200 ,
               Thumb500 = SOURCE.Thumb500 ;

SELECT  *
FROM    @DestTable;
```